# Thieves tore out my ignition switch

Tags: electrical, ford

I have a 2002 ford econoline van. They tore out the ignition switch and tried to steal it. I replaced the ignition switch but now it is like there is no power. I checked the regular fuses in the panel below the dash and under the hood and they are all good. Any ideas?

Comment: Does anything work,lights,horn,radio?

Answer (score 1):

Does the vehicle have any anti-theft systems that might need to be reset? This could have been triggered when they tore out the ignition cylinder.